# Powershell Script against outlook mail box is selecting old data

Tags: c#, email, powershell, outlook

---

I am into this project wherein emails pushed into a folder has to be cross checked whether it arrives.
So, to meet this end, I used a powershell script to connect to the mail folder and collect the data.
**The code is pasted below.**

```
 Add-Type $class -ReferencedAssemblies Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
 $class = @"
 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;public class MyOL
 {
public MAPIFolder GetInbox(string userName)
{
    Application oOutlook = new Application();
    NameSpace oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Recipient oRep = oNs.CreateRecipient(userName);
    MAPIFolder inbox = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    return inbox;
 }
}
 "@
  Add-Type $class -ReferencedAssemblies Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

 $MyOL = New-Object MyOL
$olInbox = $MyOL.GetInbox("mailbox")

 $olInbox.items | Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName
```

but this code is collecting **only a week old data!** and not the fresh emails. I did try looking around and found that this can be related to the indexes in the mailbox. So, I have tried disabling that as well but in vain.

Comment: did you tried filtering  using ***ReceivedTime*** ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't just use the ComObject for Outlook. If you want recent items only this should get you the items received in the last 24 hours:

```
$MSOut = new-object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$MAPI = $MSOut.GetNamespace("MAPI")|?{$_.SMTP -match "Some.User@Company.com"}
$Account = $MAPI.Folders|?{$_.Name -match "Some.User@Company.com"}
$Inbox = $Account.folders | ?{$_.Name -match "Inbox"}
$24hours = (get-date).AddDays(-1)
$RecentItems = $Inbox.Items|?{$_.ReceivedTime -gt $24hours}
```

Then you can run your Select against that if you want to just get certain properties, like:

```
$RecentItems | Select -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName
```

Comment: This code isn't working for me! I am a newbee to powershell scripting. Does this have anything to do with the version of the sdk?

Comment: You shouldn't need an SDK, just Office installed. Where are you getting the error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error with the code you gave me (thanks for that though) but it isnt retrieving any data as well. The code I have pasted, when u execute it, what output do you get? does it contain the    latest emails? if it does then that's the way it should work. What i get in return is a week old email list :(. i.e. when i execute it today on the 9th i get a list from the 2nd!

Comment: I get emails from the last 24 hours, as expected. I'm not sure how you could get email from a week ago when that code specifically filters for the last 24 hours. Is your Outlook current? Do you see more recent emails listed in Outlook when you open it?